# Comparing rows of a matrix and deleting items

Tags: r

I recently started using R and so there are some problems occuring ...

I got a matrix of n rows and 4 columns, somehow like that snippet.

```
matrix(c(11,12,22,0.6208233305,10,13,22,0.5349532285,10,12,21,0.8225881140,9,12,20,0.5783936215, 5,6,10,0.2577839615, 4,27,30,0.0286089882,6,23,28,0.6658443779), nrow = 7, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c(), c("Count", "Start", "End", "Value")))

matrix(c(11,12,22,0.6208233305,5,6,10,0.2577839615, 6,23,28,0.6658443779), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c(), c("Count", "Start", "End", "Value")))
```

Now I want to compare the first entry to the following entries.
If "Start" of the first entry is smaller or equal and "End" is bigger or equal to the next entry, the following entry should be erased from the matrix unless "Start" & "End" both are smaller than "Start" or bigger than "End". After the first run it should use the second entry to perform the same check again until all duplicates are erased.

The final matrix should only consist of entries where no range between "Start" and "End" can be found twice (see second matrix in the snip).

I hope you can understand my question, and I apologize for my english

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21622690/4137985

Comment: Nice input, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Nevertheless, I got a good idea how to address the problem